# how to use React Page Scroller when you have a page larger than 100vh

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm having a problem with React Page Scroller.
Most of the components that I'm using are designed to take 100vh and those work fine with React Page Scroller. The problem comes with the footer since it's larger than 100vh.
I tried leaving the footer outside of the ReactPageScroller component but it gives me 2 vertical scrolls on the screen. Meaning it scrolls down to the next component but also scrolls down to the footer.

```
<ReactPageScroller>
  <SomeComponent />
  <SomeComponent />
  <SomeComponent />
  <SomeComponent />
  <Footer />
</ReactPageScroller>
```

or

```
<ReactPageScroller>
  <SomeComponent />
  <SomeComponent />
  <SomeComponent />
  <SomeComponent />
</ReactPageScroller>
 <Footer />
```

Any ideas?
The ideal scenario would be if ones I reach the last component I'm able to scroll normally down to the footer and then if I want to go back up I should have the React Page Scroller effect again.
Please ask question if it's not yet clear what I mean

Comment: hello and welcome to SO!
Just one question do you need your footer to always be displayed or do you need to scroll down to go to it?

Comment: Hello :) I'd need to scroll down to go to it.

Answer (score 1):

After some couple of research I found a something with scroller `pageOnChange`props:
I only found example of implementation with React Class Component so I assumed that your component is a class type.
First I created a state object like :

```
 this.state = {
      currentPage: 1,
      isFooterVisble: false
    };
```

And made a function that will set the state on a page on change event:

```
 pageOnChange = (number) => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: number,
      isFooterVisble: number === 6 // 6 equals to the last component number 
    });
  };
```

And add this function to  `pageOnChange={this.pageOnChange}` of `ReactPageScroller`:

```
  <ReactPageScroller
          ref={(c) => (this._pageScroller = c)}
          pageOnChange={this.pageOnChange}
        >
```

to render the footer component I use conditional rendering with `this.state.isFooterVisble` like this:

```
  <>
        <ReactPageScroller
          ref={(c) => (this._pageScroller = c)}
          pageOnChange={this.pageOnChange}
        >
          <Comp title={"PAGE 1"} />
          <Comp title={"PAGE 2"} />
          <Comp title={"PAGE 3"} />
          <Comp title={"PAGE 4"} />
          <Comp title={"PAGE 5"} />
          <Comp title={"PAGE 6"} />
        </ReactPageScroller>
        {this.state.isFooterVisble && <Footer />}
      </>
```

and in the global css file I add this :

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  /* prevent overscroll bounce*/
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

here the complete component code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactPageScroller from "react-page-scroller";
import Comp from "./component";
import Footer from "./footer";

export default class Scroller extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentPage: 1,
      isFooterVisble: false
    };
    this._pageScroller = null;
  }

  goToPage = (eventKey) => {
    this._pageScroller.goToPage(eventKey);
  };

  pageOnChange = (number) => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: number,
      isFooterVisble: number === 6
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ReactPageScroller
          ref={(c) => (this._pageScroller = c)}
          pageOnChange={this.pageOnChange}
        >
          <Comp title={"PAGE 1"} />
          <Comp title={"PAGE 2"} />
          <Comp title={"PAGE 3"} />
          <Comp title={"PAGE 4"} />
          <Comp title={"PAGE 5"} />
          <Comp title={"PAGE 6"} />
        </ReactPageScroller>
        {this.state.isFooterVisble && <Footer />}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit elegant-shape-j0u4c]